# Insert a html tag in between an existing html tag programatically

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Data</td>
            <td>Some Data</td>
            <td>Some Data</td>
            <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add `</tr><tr>` in between the row programatically at runtime:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Data</td>
            <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>Some Data</td>
            <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried `$('tr td').eq(1).after('</tr><tr>');`, but it instead gave:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Data</td>
            <td>Some Data</td>
        </tr/>
        <tr/>
            <td>Some Data</td>
            <td>Some Data</td>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, how can I achieve the required functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of string manipulation, you are inserting `"<tr></tr>"`.

In terms of DOM manipulation, however, you are making a new tr and moving two of the children of the original to it. If you use DOM manipulation tools, you have to follow the DOM manipulation logic.

```
$('tr').eq(0).after('<tr></tr>');
$($('tr td').eq(1).nextAll()).appendTo($('tr').eq(1));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to split the row into two. You could do this using the following:

```
​$(function() {
    $('tbody tr').each(function() {  
        var cells = $(this).children('td'),
             row1 = $('<tr />'),
             row2 = $('<tr />');

        row1.append(cells[0]).append(cells[1]);
        row2.append(cells[2]).append(cells[3]);

        $(this).replaceWith(row1.add(row2));
    });​​​​​​​
});
```

Please see the sample jsFiddle here > http://jsfiddle.net/ayYa5/

Comment: Hey buddy, your was good enough, but @Asad 's answer seems better performance-wise as well as to eyes... :)

Comment: Thanks. Just be cautious though, as his solution will only work for the first `<tr>` element.

Comment: Hey, yeah, but that isn't of much concern... :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
$('<tr></tr>').appendTo($('tbody'));
$('tbody tr:first-child td:last-child').appendTo($('tbody tr:last-child'));
$('tbody tr:first-child td:last-child').appendTo($('tbody tr:last-child'));
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PKGtH/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it heavily depends on the format of data you have, but here's what you can try:

```
$( "td" ).unwrap( );

var wrap_tds = function( ) {
    var els = $( "tbody" ).children( "td:lt(2)" );
    if (els.length) {
        els.wrap( "tr" );
        wrap_tds( );
    }
};
wrap_tds( );
```